# How to write encrypted data in a file using pycrypto?

Tags: python, pycrypto

I have been using RSA Public/Private Key Pair to encrpyt data:

```
random_generator = Random.new().read
key = RSA.generate(1024, random_generator)
publickey = key.publickey()
```

and write it to a file. The probelm I am getting is when I read any file in bytes:

```
f = open('test','rb')
d = f.read()
enc_data = publickey.encrypt(d,32)
```

I am getting the encrypted data as a tuple

```
>>> type(enc_data)
>>> <class 'tuple'>
```

The problem is when I try to write the encrypted text in any newly created file I am not able to do it in any mode

```
o = open('out','wb') #same with 'w' mode
o.write(enc_data)
```

It displays the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#103>", line 1, in <module>
o.write(enc_data)
TypeError: must be str, not tuple
```

How to get my encrypted data saved?

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I got my answer!

Comment: `publickey.emcrytp(d,32)`, really? :)

Answer (score 0):

According to [these docs](https://pythonhosted.org/pycrypto/Crypto.PublicKey.RSA._RSAobj-class.html#encrypt), the `encrypt` function returns a tuple, where the second value is always `None`. I'm assuming this is to support backwards compatibility. Try:

```
enc_data, other =  publickey.encrypt(d,32)
```

Then write `enc_data` (this is called "ciphertext")

In the future, it would be a good idea to explicitly say what library you are using. Also `emcrytp`...

Comment: that asked for 1 more value, but I got my answer from the duplicate suggestion by Garrett Hyde! :) Thanks a lot btw :)